# Create exercices document

Tags: tikz-pgf, exercises

Good morning friends; can you help me create this document [image]. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to show what you have so far :)

Comment: I suggest you write to the author of this document and ask him for his code ;) Otherwise, it would be nice to create your own template and come for help with what you tried, especially since I already helped you with *copying* a template before.